# In Windbg, can I skip breaking when specific C++ exceptions are thrown?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, windbg

In Visual Studio, through the dialog at Debug > Exceptions..., you can set specific C++ exceptions types to break on or skip past. In Windbg, turning on breaking for C++ exceptions with `sxe eh` is all or nothing.

Is there any way to skip breaking on specific C++ exception types? Conversely, is there a way to break on only specific types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is 32-bit specific, as I haven't yet done much 64-bit debugging. I don't know how much applies to 64-bit.

Assume the following code:

```
class foo_exception : public std::exception {};

void throw_foo()
{
    throw foo_exception();
}
```

And let's assume you've turned on breaking on first chance exceptions for C++ exceptions: `sxe eh`

Now when the debugger breaks, your exception record will be on the top of the stack. So if you just want to see what the type is, you can display the exception record info:

```
0:000> .exr @esp
ExceptionAddress: 751dc42d (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000058)
   ExceptionCode: e06d7363 (C++ EH exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: 19930520
   Parameter[1]: 0027f770
   Parameter[2]: 0122ada0
  pExceptionObject: 0027f770
  _s_ThrowInfo    : 0122ada0
  Type            : class foo_exception
  Type            : class std::exception
```

Take a look at the current stack, and you can see where this stuff is sitting:

```
    0027f6c4  e06d7363
    0027f6c8  00000001
    0027f6cc  00000000
    0027f6d0  751dc42d KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
    0027f6d4  00000003
    0027f6d8  19930520
    0027f6dc  0027f770
    0027f6e0  0122ada0 langD!_TI2?AVfoo_exception
    ...
```

So the exception itself is sitting at `0027f770` in this example, as you can see from the `.exr` output next to `pExceptionObject`. And you can see that value on the stack at `0027f6dc`, or offset from the top of the stack by 0x18, so `@esp+18`. Let's see what the debugger tells us about that location.

```
0:000> dpp @esp+18 L1
0027f6dc  0027f770 01225ffc langD!foo_exception::`vftable'
```

This command says: starting at `@esp+18`, **d**ump one **p**ointer-sized value, then deref the value found there as a **p**ointer, too, and write the name of any symbol matching that second address. And in this case it found the vtable for the `foo_exception` class. That tells us that the object at address `0027f770` is a `foo_exception`. And we can use that information to create an expression for a conditional breakpoint.

We need a way to get the address of the vtable directly, and that looks like this:

```
@!"langD!foo_exception::`vftable'"
```

We have to quote it because of the back tick and apostraphe. We also need to pull the desired stack value:

```
poi(poi(@esp+18))
```

The `poi` operator takes an address and returns a pointer-sized value stored there. The first evaluation turns the stack address into the object address, and the second evaluation turns the object address into the vtable address, which we need for comparison. The whole condition looks like this:

```
@!"langD!foo_exception::`vftable'" == poi(poi(@esp+18))
```

Now that we can tell if it's a `foo_exception`, we can skip breaking on them by setting a command to run automatically when the debugger breaks on C++ exceptions:

```
sxe -c".if ( @!\"langD!foo_exception::`vftable'\" == poi(poi(@esp+18)) ) {gc}" eh
```

Translation:

- break on first chance for C++ exceptions and run a command that:
- compares the `foo_exception` vtable address to the vtable address of the object at `@esp+18`
- if they are the same, issue the `gc` command, which continues running if the debugger was running when this command was reached
- (don't forget to escape the inner quotes)

And if you want to break *only* for a `foo_exception`, change the condition from `==` to `!=`.

Something to keep in mind is that sometimes exceptions are thrown as a pointer instead of by value, which means you'll need one more `poi()` around the `@esp` part of the expression. You'll be able to tell because when you dump the exception record with `.exr`, the `Type` will be `class foo_expression *`. This is completely dependent on the code that throws the exception and not the exception type itself, so you may need to tailor your `.if`-condition for the situtation.

Lastly, if you want to break on or skip several exception types, it is doable. I would suggest [writing a script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566261.aspx) with the chained `.if`, `.elsif` commands and setting the`sxe` automatic command to `$$><path\to\script`. Doing a ton of if-condition chaining on one line can be very difficult to read and get right, especially with the extra escaping. A script won't need the extra escaping. Here's a small example:

```
.if ( @!"langD!foo_exception::`vftable'" == poi(poi(@esp+0x18)) )
{
    $$ skip foo_exceptions
    gc
}
.elsif ( @!"langD!bar_exception::`vftable'" == poi(poi(@esp+0x18)) )
{
    $$ dump the exception to see the error message, then continue running
    dt poi(@esp+18) langD!bar_exception
    gc
}
.elsif ( @!"langD!baz_exception::`vftable'" == poi(poi(@esp+0x18)) )
{
    $$ show the top 10 frames of the stack and then break (because we don't `gc`)
    kc 10
}
```

(Note: Windbg will complain about a script error whenever this runs because it doesn't like a `gc` command followed by anything else. But it still runs fine)

Comment: Wow. What a mess. :-) Seems the VS debugger is good for something after all.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit complicated to do it manually, but at least the power to do it exists. If Visual Studio didn't already have this baked in, would it even be possible to add it yourself? Plus, someone could take the information here and package it into a Windbg extension that would be as easy to use as visual Studio.